# Calling bash in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, bash

I need to call a bash Script Out of my Python Script.

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call("path/to/script.sh")
```

This is working, but the Script is starting another programm and therefore wont Exit. So my main Loop is blocked by the subprocess.

Is there a way to call the Script as Thread, not subprocess in Python?

Comment: I really doubt it is working with the capital `I`.

Comment: But in general: An other script is always an other process. (with the exception of an other Python script being imported.) You have to use the `Popen()` class directly, not one of the convenience functions in the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `call`; its only purpose is to block until the command exits. Use `Popen` directly:

```
import subprocess 
p = subprocess.Popen("path/to/script.sh")
```

Now `script.sh` runs in the forked process while your Python script continues. Use `p.wait()` when you are ready to check if the script has completed.

Answer (score 7):

You're better off using [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

> Execute a child program in a new process. On Unix, the class uses
>   os.execvp()-like behavior to execute the child program. On Windows,
>   the class uses the Windows CreateProcess() function. The arguments to
>   Popen are as follows

But if you insist on using `threads` this might also work:

```
import subprocess 
import threading


def basher():
    subprocess.call("echo hello > /tmp/test.txt", shell=True)


t = threading.Thread(target=basher)
t.start()
print('started')
# doing something else
t.join()
print('finished')
```

Comment: In fact, `call` is just an extremely thin wrapper that immediately waits on a process created by `Popen`: `def call(*popenargs, **kwargs): return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()`.

Answer (score -1):

Since you specifically asked for a separate thread, I recommend using the `multiprocessing` module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html%22documentation%22)):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import subprocess

def myTask():
    subprocess.call("path/to/script.sh")

p = Process(target=myTask)  # creates a new thread which will run the function myTask 
p.start()  # starts the thread

# the script is now running in a separate thread
# you can now continue doing what you want
```

If at some point in your python script (e.g. before exiting) you want to make sure that the bash script has finished running you can call `p.join()` which blocks the python script until the bash script has terminated.

Comment: This is really wrong: "In multiprocessing, processes are spawned by creating a Process object". A process is *not* a thread -- a thread is *not* a process. You're not starting a separate thread here, you're starting a process!